# how to self-publish android app

Tags: android

Hi i'm wondering what is the process i have to follow in order to self-publish an app in my website. Is it just to put the .apk file in the website and provide a link to the user to navigate (from the phone) to the app and install it?

1. Would the user need some extra knowledge to be able to install the app?
2. Can the user install it with one click?
3. What about updates, can the user get a notification when there's a new version?
4. Would the user need to unistall and reinstall the app when upgrading to a newer version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- No extra knowledge, and they can install with one click. They DO however have to have installation of "non-market applications" enabled in the settings.
- Update notifications can only work if you program it in your app. Request some sort of flag from your site or something. So no basic support for that
- You don't need to uninstall and reinstall. Mind your versionNumber though.

Comment: What if i sign the application like this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/  Would the user still need have "non-market applications" enabled in the settings?

Comment: Yes. For all apks you're not installing from the market, you need to have that checkbox enabled as far as I know. And that is it's intention, so if you find a way around that (which i doubt), you can just wait for  it to be 'fixed' later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*  
 *  Code Prepared by Muhammad Mubashir.
 *  Analyst Software Engineer.
    Emial Id : muhammad.mubashir.bscs@gmail.com
    Skype Id : muhammad.mubashir.ansari
    Code: August, 2011.

    Description: Get Updates(means New .Apk File) from IIS Server and Download it on Device SD Card,
                 and Uninstall Previous (means OLD .apk) and Install New One.
                 and also get Installed App Version Code & Version Name.

    All Rights Reserved.
*/
package com.SelfInstall01;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.SelfInstall01.SelfInstall01Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SelfInstall01Activity extends Activity 
{
    class PInfo {
        private String appname = "";
        private String pname = "";
        private String versionName = "";
        private int versionCode = 0;
        //private Drawable icon;
        /*private void prettyPrint() {
            //Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
        }*/
    }
    public int VersionCode;
    public String VersionName="";
    public String ApkName ;
    public String AppName ;
    public String BuildVersionPath="";
    public String urlpath ;
    public String PackageName;
    public String InstallAppPackageName;
    public String Text="";

    TextView tvApkStatus;
    Button btnCheckUpdates;
    TextView tvInstallVersion;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Text= "Old".toString();
        Text= "New".toString();


        ApkName = "SelfInstall01.apk";//"Test1.apk";// //"DownLoadOnSDcard_01.apk"; //      
        AppName = "SelfInstall01";//"Test1"; //

        BuildVersionPath = "http://10.0.2.2:82/Version.txt".toString();
        PackageName = "package:com.SelfInstall01".toString(); //"package:com.Test1".toString();
        urlpath = "http://10.0.2.2:82/"+ Text.toString()+"_Apk/" + ApkName.toString();

        tvApkStatus =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvApkStatus);
        tvApkStatus.setText(Text+" Apk Download.".toString());


        tvInstallVersion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInstallVersion);
        String temp = getInstallPackageVersionInfo(AppName.toString());
        tvInstallVersion.setText("" +temp.toString());

        btnCheckUpdates =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckUpdates);
        btnCheckUpdates.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                GetVersionFromServer(BuildVersionPath); 

                if(checkInstalledApp(AppName.toString()) == true)
                {   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Found " + AppName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Not Found. "+ AppName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
                }               
            }
        });

    }// On Create END.

    private Boolean checkInstalledApp(String appName){
        return getPackages(appName);    
    }

    // Get Information about Only Specific application which is Install on Device.
    public String getInstallPackageVersionInfo(String appName) 
    {
        String InstallVersion = "";     
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++) 
        {
            //apps.get(i).prettyPrint();        
            if(apps.get(i).appname.toString().equals(appName.toString()))
            {
                InstallVersion = "Install Version Code: "+ apps.get(i).versionCode+
                    " Version Name: "+ apps.get(i).versionName.toString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return InstallVersion.toString();
    }
    private Boolean getPackages(String appName) 
    {
        Boolean isInstalled = false;
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++) 
        {
            //apps.get(i).prettyPrint();

            if(apps.get(i).appname.toString().equals(appName.toString()))
            {
                /*if(apps.get(i).versionName.toString().contains(VersionName.toString()) == true &&
                        VersionCode == apps.get(i).versionCode)
                {
                    isInstalled = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Code Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    openMyDialog();
                }*/
                if(VersionCode <= apps.get(i).versionCode)
                {
                    isInstalled = true;

                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Install Code is Less.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which)
                            {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                //Yes button clicked
                                //SelfInstall01Activity.this.finish(); Close The App.

                                DownloadOnSDcard();
                                InstallApplication();
                                UnInstallApplication(PackageName.toString());

                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("New Apk Available..").setPositiveButton("Yes Proceed", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No.", dialogClickListener).show();

                }    
                if(VersionCode > apps.get(i).versionCode)
                {
                    isInstalled = true;
                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Install Code is better.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which)
                            {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                //Yes button clicked
                                //SelfInstall01Activity.this.finish(); Close The App.

                                DownloadOnSDcard();
                                InstallApplication();
                                UnInstallApplication(PackageName.toString());

                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("NO need to Install.").setPositiveButton("Install Forcely", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel.", dialogClickListener).show();              
                }
            }
        }

        return isInstalled;
    }
    private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) 
    {       
        ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

        for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) 
        {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
                continue ;
            }
            PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            //newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            res.add(newInfo);
        }
        return res; 
    }


    public void UnInstallApplication(String packageName)// Specific package Name Uninstall.
    {
        //Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.CheckInstallApp");
        Uri packageURI = Uri.parse(packageName.toString());
        Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
        startActivity(uninstallIntent); 
    }
    public void InstallApplication()
    {   
        Uri packageURI = Uri.parse(PackageName.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageURI);

//      Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);

        //intent.setAction(Settings. ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);

        intent.setDataAndType
        (Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"  + ApkName.toString())), 
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        // Not open this Below Line Because...
        ////intent.setClass(this, Project02Activity.class); // This Line Call Activity Recursively its dangerous.

        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    public void GetVersionFromServer(String BuildVersionPath)
    {
        //this is the file you want to download from the remote server          
        //path ="http://10.0.2.2:82/Version.txt";
        //this is the name of the local file you will create
        // version.txt contain Version Code = 2; \n Version name = 2.1;             
        URL u;
        try {
            u = new URL(BuildVersionPath.toString());

            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();           
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HttpURLConnection Complete.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //that stops the reading after 1024 chars..
            //in.read(buffer); //  Read from Buffer.
            //baos.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

            int len1 = 0;
            while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1 ) 
            {               
                baos.write(buffer,0, len1); // Write Into ByteArrayOutputStream Buffer.
            }

            String temp = "";     
            String s = baos.toString();// baos.toString(); contain Version Code = 2; \n Version name = 2.1;

            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            {               
                i = s.indexOf("=") + 1; 
                while (s.charAt(i) == ' ') // Skip Spaces
                {
                    i++; // Move to Next.
                }
                while (s.charAt(i) != ';'&& (s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9' || s.charAt(i) == '.'))
                {
                    temp = temp.toString().concat(Character.toString(s.charAt(i))) ;
                    i++;
                }
                //
                s = s.substring(i); // Move to Next to Process.!
                temp = temp + " "; // Separate w.r.t Space Version Code and Version Name.
            }
            String[] fields = temp.split(" ");// Make Array for Version Code and Version Name.

            VersionCode = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].toString());// .ToString() Return String Value.
            VersionName = fields[1].toString();

            baos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            //return true;
    }// Method End.

    // Download On My Mobile SDCard or Emulator.
    public void DownloadOnSDcard()
    {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlpath.toString()); // Your given URL.

            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect(); // Connection Complete here.!

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HttpURLConnection complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH); // PATH = /mnt/sdcard/download/
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            File outputFile = new File(file, ApkName.toString());           
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD Card Path: " + outputFile.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream(); // Get from Server and Catch In Input Stream Object.

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1); // Write In FileOutputStream.
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file.
            // So please Check in DDMS tab and Select your Emulator.

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Complete on SD Card.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //download the APK to sdcard then fire the Intent.
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! " +
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
    }
}
```

**XML Permissions.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.SelfInstall01"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SelfInstall01Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Why do you call .toString() on every string literal?

Answer (score 0):

-Would the user need some extra knowledge to be able to install the app?
Yes. You can't install non-signed application without authorizing installation of "Unknown sources" at the applications settings.

-Can the user install it with one click?
Nope . He has to get your site , download it , open it and approve that he want's to install it.

-What about updates, can the user get a notification when there's a new version?
I think update support is only for market apps. You'll need to write something yourself

-Would the user need to unistall and reinstall the app when upgrading to a newer version?
See answer above - depends on how you implement it.